# Decorating named components in windsor

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

My assembly contains multiple implementations of IFoo. One of those implementations is decorator FooDecorator. Additionally I have FooFactory which I would like to resolve all Foos decorated by FooDecorator. I assumed that best way will be to resolve components by name. My current registration looks like this:

```
Component.For<IFooFactory>()
    .ImplementedBy<WindsorFooFactory>()
    .LifestyleSingleton(),
Component.For<IFoo>()
    .ImplementedBy<FooDecorator>(),
AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn<IFoo>()
    .Configure(c => c
        .Named(c.Implementation.Name))));
```

And implementation of factory looks like this:

```
public class WindsorFooFactory : IFooFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _container;

    public WindsorFooFactory(IKernel container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IFoo NewFoo(Type fooType)
    {
        return _container.Resolve<IFoo>(fooType.Name);
    }

    public void ReturnFoo(IFoo foo)
    {
        _container.ReleaseComponent(foo);
    }
}
```

So if my assembly contains Foo1, Foo2 and FooDecorator I should have such registrations:

1. component for IFoo implemented by FooDecorator
2. component for IFoo implemented by Foo1 named Foo1
3. component for IFoo implemented by Foo2 named Foo2
4. // component for IFoo implemented by FooDecorator named FooDecorator
   <-- not sure about this as this is duplicate

Now my factory would be resolving components like:

```
container.Resolve("Foo1")
```

And I would like to receive Foo1 decorated by FooDecorator.
Is there any way to achieve such decoration? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: not sure to understand your goal. Would you like resolve IFoo and be sure you get the decorator or you'd like to get a specific IFoo regardless the decorator?

Comment: @CristianoDegiorgis I would like to resolve IFoo named "Foo1" and get Foo1 decorated by FooDecorator. I have updated my question with example registration.

Comment: It seems you don't want a decorator, but an interceptor instead.

Comment: @CristianoDegiorgis Yes, I think that interceptor would work. However this decorator already exists, I just need to wire things up.

Comment: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx?HL=interceptor

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use interceptor that configuration should work for you

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<FooInterceptor>(),
    Classes.FromAssembly()
        .BasedOn<IFoo>()
        .Configure(c => c.Interceptors<FooInterceptor>())
        .Configure(c => c.Named(c.Implementation.Name)));
```

Of course you have to implement your FooInterceptor implementing IInterceptor

You should also considering to replace your factory with a [TypedFactory](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx?HL=typedfactory)

Comment: I really like this solution, unfortunately I need to use decorator. +1 for typed factory, cool thing.